# Is creating an object with methods defined on it via a function less memory efficient than creating an instance of a class?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I were to write a class (this has no literal meaning I'm just writing some BS)

```
class A {
  constructor(name, date) {
    this.nameDateString = name + date;
  }
  someMethod() {
    return `${this.nameDateString} ${this.nameDateString}`;
  }
  addAnotherNameDateString(name, date) {
    this.nameDateString += name + date;
  }
}
```

Would writing a function that creates a closure (am I using this term right?) on some data by defining some functions and returning them:

```
const createA = (name, date) => {
  let nameDateString = name + date;
  const someMethod = () => {
    return `${nameDateString} ${nameDateString}`;
  }
  const addAnotherNameDateString = (name, date) => {
    nameDateString += name + date;
  }
  return { someMethod, addAnotherNameDateString };
}
```

be less efficient in terms of memory?

For example, would

```
Array(100000).fill(null).map((_, i) => new A(i, new Date() + i*123456))
```

be more advantageous than:

```
Array(100000).fill(null).map((_, i) => createA(i, new Date() + i*123456))
```

Comment: I've updated my answer now to clarify re the comment you made to me on AKX's answer. :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just up front: Programming using a style with `createA` or similar is quite common; it's one of the popular ways is JavaScript is used.  Programming with `class A` or similar is also quite common, and one of the (perhaps slightly more) popular ways JavaScript is used.

> Would [creating different functions each time] be less efficient in terms of memory?

Yes, a bit, for a couple of different reasons: function objects and the closure. But whether that *matters* is another thing entirely, relative to other objectives/concerns.

With your `class`, the function objects for the methods are on `A.prototype` and are *reused* by each instance of the class (they're inherited from the prototype assigned to them):

```js
class A {
  constructor(name, date) {
    this.nameDateString = name + date;
  }
  someMethod() {
    return `${this.nameDateString} ${this.nameDateString}`;
  }
  addAnotherNameDateString(name, date) {
    this.nameDateString += name + date;
  }
}

const a1 = new A("Joe", new Date());
const a2 = new A("Mary", new Date());
console.log(a1.someMethod === a2.someMethod); // true
```

With your `createA` function, *different* function objects for those methods are created every time `createA` is called:

```js
const createA = (name, date) => {
  let nameDateString = name + date;
  const someMethod = () => {
    return `${nameDateString} ${nameDateString}`;
  }
  const addAnotherNameDateString = (name, date) => {
    nameDateString += name + date;
  }
  return { someMethod, addAnotherNameDateString };
}

const a1 = createA("Joe", new Date());
const a2 = createA("Mary", new Date());

console.log(a1.someMethod === a2.someMethod); // false
```

So the objects created by `createA` have a larger memory imprint than the objects created by `new A`, because they have their own copies of those function objects (and because of the closure, more in a moment).

But, function objects aren't that big. The underlying *code* (the bytecode and/or machine code created by parsing the source text) will be reused (by any half-decent JavaScript engine). That is, the code for `someMethod` will be reused by the multiple function objects created for `someMethod` by different calls to `createA`. Suppose we have:

```
const a1 = createA("Joe", new Date());
const a2 = createA("Mary", new Date());
```

Then we end up with something *something* like this in memory (lots of details omitted, of course):

```
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−+
a1−−>|  (object)  |
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
     | someMethod |−−−>|     (function)     |
     | ...        |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−+    | name: "someMethod" |
                       | length: 0          |     
                    +−−| [[Environment]]    |
                    |  | {{Code}}           |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  
                    |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+               |  
                    |                                       |  
                    |        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                    +−−−−−−−>|   (environment object)    |  |
                             +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                             | nameDateString: "Joe..."  |  |
                             +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  |
                                                            |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−+                                         +−>|     (code)      |
a2−−>|  (object)  |                                         |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−+    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+               |  | 100100001000... |
     | someMethod |−−−>|     (function)     |               |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
     | ...        |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+               |
     +−−−−−−−−−−−−+    | name: "someMethod" |               |
                       | length: 0          |               |  
                    +−−| [[Environment]]    |               |  
                    |  | {{Code}}           |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+  
                    |  +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+                  
                    |
                    |        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                    +−−−−−−−>|   (environment object)    |
                             +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                             | nameDateString: "Mary..." |
                             +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

That diagram points out the other slight difference: The `createA` style will keep the environment object for the call to `createA` in memory, since `someMethod` and `addAnotherNameDateString` close over that environment. So instead of a single object created and retained by `new A`, you have four objects created and retained by `createA`:

- The object `createA` returns.
- A function object for `someMethod`...
- ...and `addAnotherNameDateString`
- The lexical environment object they close over

In contrast, `new A` just produces one object.

But understanding that, if the `createA` style fits your goals better than the `class A` style, or vice-versa, use the one that fits your goals. The size difference is unlikely to matter for 100,000 instances (even on mobile devices; but certainly it might in an embedded environment). But if you're in the millions, you may well need to start thinking about avoiding memory pressure.

If you're worried about the memory impact, measure it with your real code. In major browsers, you can use a Memory tab in the dev tools to help you measure the impact of your code choices on memory consumption.

Answer (score 1):

This is dependent on the JavaScript engine running your program; some engines could be clever enough to realize that `createA`'s functions are always the same but with different closures, and optimize accordingly. You would need to measure both approaches to see for sure. (As discussed in the comments, any major engine these days will likely optimize things enough that the underlying code object is shared between functions, even if the variable closure is different.)

With a `class`, the engine doesn't need to be clever since the methods are on the `prototype` of the class, and it's more idiomatic these days anyway, so I'd just go with that.

Comment: There's no cleverness involved. The same function construct in the same parse position will get code emitted that's reused for different instances of that function. But similarly, different function objects are **required** for the OP's case, they can't be consolidated.

Comment: OP edited in the `nameDateString` stuff after my answer ;-)

Comment: I don't think that matters to what you said or my comment on it. :-)

Comment: How could I measure that?

Comment: @Simponic your browser likely has a memory measurement tool in the developer tools.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, I don't know, I could happily write a naïve JavaScript engine that creates new function [and code] objects for each invocation of the `createA` function as it interprets the code :) And I'm pretty sure such engines are out in the wild even today.

Comment: @AKX - It's not naive to create a new function object each time `createA` is called, it's *required* by the specification. (The underlying code, though, is a different thing entirely. Yes, there probably have been naive engines out there that replicated the code, though I doubt there have been any time in the last decade. Certainly none of the major engines is silly enough to do that. :-) )

Comment: @Simponic - It would be a different function object (see my answer). But the bytecode and/or machine code produced by parsing the source code would be reused between those function objects (on any half-decent JavaScript engine). I'll beef up that part of my answer.